# Generate csv headers for list of objects

Tags: c#, mapping, csvhelper

I'm trying to get from class like:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<decimal> SomeValues{get;set;
}
```

the csv file with headers like:

```
Name;SomeV 1;SomeV 2;...;SomeV N;
Alpha;1;2;...;N;
```

How i could achive that with custom PersonRowMap : ClassMap< Person >?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Index` along with the `indexEnd` value to determine the start and ending columns for the `SomeValues1`, `SomeValues2` etc.  You can also use `Name` to change the name used for the columns.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var records = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person { Name = "Alpha", SomeValues = new List<decimal> {1, 2, 3} },
    };

    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var someValueCount = records.First().SomeValues.Count();
        
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap(new PersonMap(someValueCount));
        csv.WriteRecords(records);
    }
}

public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonMap(int someValueCount) 
    {
        Map(x => x.Name).Index(0);
        Map(x => x.SomeValues).Name("SomeV ").Index(1,someValueCount);
    }   
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<decimal> SomeValues { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Great, thx a lot! Also maybe you could provide an example for Person::List<SomeObject> to generate columns with names like "SomeObject.Field1 + " " + SomeObject.Field2"?

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately, this only works with `List<SomeValue>`.  `List<SomeObject>` is going to be a bit more complex.  I'm not quite following how you want the headers and the data to look.  Maybe you can start another question and give an example of how exactly you want the data to look? Is that what the header is going to look like? That's not standard CSV. The quotes in the middle would have to be escaped with another set of double quotes. And that's only SomeObject1? What would SomeObject2 look like?